# tomcat server sql exception

Tags: kotlin, tomcat, spring-jdbc

I have an app that runs the Tomcat server. I use IntelliJ on my machine and run it from there when I do tests.

Running it many times, all works, and suddenly server do not go up well, and I see the following in log:

```
com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#1: BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@1ab64513 -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30). Last acquisition attempt exception: 
java.sql.SQLException: Unexpected exception encountered during query.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1073)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:987)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:982)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:927)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2664)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2568)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1557)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.loadServerVariables(ConnectionImpl.java:3868)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.initializePropsFromServer(ConnectionImpl.java:3407)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2384)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2153)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:792)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor38.newInstance(Unknown Source)
```

I have no clue what happened since I did not change anything related to JDBC or SQL. I tried to replace kotlin version (upgrade) and returned right away, but I don't know if it has anything to do with the exception, and how can I solve it.

checking the connection to the database from IntelliJ DB pane - connected successfully.

I will be thankful if someone has a clue what could go wrong.

Comment: What version of MySQL JDBC driver used?  Updating the drvier may help to resolve this issue - https://www.imooc.com/qadetail/302176

Comment: 5.1.18
but I tried with 8.0.26 - same issue.

Comment: com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#0: BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@677f24f7 -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30). Last acquisition attempt exception: 
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from